# Why I do not get the broadcast?

Tags: android

I have the following code to send long SMS.

As you can see in the code I truncate the long test in parts and 
I send the parts with the SmsManager

providing an ArrayList of PendingIntents (for SMS set and SMS delivered).

I register two BroadcastReceivers for the PendingIntents.

The problem is that the BroadcastReceivers seem to receive nothing, and therefore they are left there hanging, waiting for the broadcast that apparently never arrives...

```
public void sendViaSms(String nexmoNumber, String message) {
    initSmsReceivers();

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            //CREATE THE PARTS OF THE SMS
    ArrayList<String> parts =sms.divideMessage(message);
    int numParts = parts.size();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    //POPULATE THE ARRAY OF PENDINGINTENTS
            for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
    sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MessageCompose.this, 0,  new Intent(SENT), 0));
    deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MessageCompose.this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0));
    }
            //SEND THE SMS IN PARTS WITH THE ARRAY OF PENDINGINTENTS
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(nexmoNumber,null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
}   

    //CREATE AND REGISTER THE BROADCASTRECEIVERS 
private void initSmsReceivers() {
    if (receiversInitialized) {
        return;
    }

    receiversInitialized = true;

    sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context contex, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                progressDialog.cancel();
                showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.email_send_failed);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context contex, Intent intent) {
            if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                return;
            }

            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                showSuccessDialog();
                break;
            default:
                showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.email_send_failed);
                break;
            }

            progressDialog.cancel();


        }
    };

    MessageCompose.this.registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    MessageCompose.this.registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(SENT));

}
```

Comment: Did you defined your receivers in the manifast?

Comment: Make sure you have the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the permission declared in your manifest? (use the appropriated one)

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```